# Why do I only able to retrieve the last row of data instead of all the rows? I'm trying to populate a list of rows into a ListView here

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, listview, loops

It keeps displaying the last row of data when I already do a whole list of search using the SQL statement that i provided it

```
        try
        {
            string strPatients = "SELECT patientID FROM MEDICALHISTORY";
            SqlCommand cmdPatient = new SqlCommand(strPatients, connection);

            string strMedicalPatients = "SELECT pFirstName, pLastName FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID=@searchPatient";
            SqlCommand cmdPatientHistory = new SqlCommand(strMedicalPatients, connection);

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader readPatientID = cmdPatient.ExecuteReader();
            if (readPatientID.Read())
            {
                string getID = readPatientID["patientID"].ToString();
                cmdPatientHistory.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchPatient", getID);
            }
            readPatientID.Close();

            SqlDataReader readPatients = cmdPatientHistory.ExecuteReader();

            while (readPatients.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem allPatients = new ListViewItem(readPatients["pFirstName"].ToString());
                allPatients.SubItems.Add(readPatients["pLastName"].ToString());

                lsMedicalHistory.Items.Add(allPatients);
            }
            readPatients.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Any idea how do I solve this problem?  I have been debugging it all day and still no luck of figuring it out.  Thanks

Regards,
Tyler

Comment: It is unclear whether the problem is the display of your list, or the data contained within the list. How many items does `lsMedicalHistory` contain if you set a breakpoint at the end of the finally block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can deduct from your code this is what I think you're trying to do:

1. Get all the patientid's from MedicalHistory
2. For each of these ID's you want to get the details from PATIENT (so I assume it's a 1-1 relationship)

The problem you have is that although your first query retrieves multiple values, you only read in the first one and then close the connection:

```
if (readPatientID.Read())
{
    string getID = readPatientID["patientID"].ToString();
    cmdPatientHistory.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchPatient", getID);
}
readPatientID.Close();
```

When this is done you effectively execute the second command with just one ID, which returns exactly one result, which is why you are seeing only one item.

You could get rid of the first query and construct the second query like this:

```
SELECT pFirstName, pLastName FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID in (select patientid from MedicalHistory)
```

Now you just need to iterate over those results. The complete code would look something like this (typed in here, so you might need to fix the possible typos):

```
 try
    {
        string strMedicalPatients = "SELECT pFirstName, pLastName FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID in (select patientid from MedicalHistory)";
        SqlCommand cmdPatientHistory = new SqlCommand(strMedicalPatients, connection);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader readPatients = cmdPatientHistory.ExecuteReader();

        while (readPatients.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem allPatients = new ListViewItem(readPatients["pFirstName"].ToString());
            allPatients.SubItems.Add(readPatients["pLastName"].ToString());

            lsMedicalHistory.Items.Add(allPatients);
        }
        readPatients.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Hey it works, but it's actually a 1 - many relationship.  A patient may have many medical history record.  So the names are ought to get repeated.  What if there's more than 1 relationships - let's say two.  How do I construct the query